# Question on uniqueness of minimal normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $H$ be minimal normal $p$-sylow subgroup of a group $G$.

Order of $G$ is $ap^{m}$ where gcd$(a,p^m) = 1$

Since $H$ is normal $p-SSG$ it implies that is unique of that order *i.e.* $H$ is the only subgroup of order $p^m$.

But how does it imply that $H$ will be unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "minimal normal $p$-Sylow subgroup"?

Comment: Isn't $G=\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ a counterexample to this? $H=\Bbb Z_2$ is a $2$-Sylow subgroup which is also a minimal normal subgroup, but it is not unique since the same is true of $\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are assuming and what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $6$. Then the subgroups of order $2$ and $3$ are both minimal normal subgroups (because their index are prime), but they are not equal, not even isomorphic.